# Image not displaying in react-native but all other data does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Please I have Card which will display data from my database, the problem its not displaying the image, but it displays the rest of the data.

```
<FlatList
        data={getListingsApi.data}
        keyExtractor={(listing) => listing.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Card
            title={item.title}
            subtitle={"₦" + item.price}
            date={item.date_of_event}
            imageUrl={item.photo}
            category={item.category}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.LISTING_DETAILS, item)}
          />
```

This is the image url of how it displays on when i log it  -
"photo": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/posts/n3.jpg",

Card Component:

```
function Card({ title, subtitle, date, category, imageUrl, onPress }) {
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={styles.card}>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          tint="light"
          preview={{ uri: imageUrl }}
          uri={imageUrl}
        />
        {/* <Image style={styles.image} source={image} /> */}

        <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
          <AppText style={styles.title}>{title}</AppText>
          <AppText style={styles.subtitle}>{subtitle}</AppText>
          <AppText style={styles.subtitle}>{date}</AppText>
          <AppText style={styles.subtitle}>{category}</AppText>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}
```

Comment: Need to include how you display the image in your card component.

Comment: can you please show me a `card` component's code

Comment: I have added it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using android emulator you have to use `10.0.2.2` to access localhost on your PC. and if you're using a real device then you need to be on the same wifi network and have to use your PC's ip instead of `localhost`

But still there is multiple tricks for show image from various source.

**Image show From project's assets folder :**

```
<Image
  source={{ uri: 'asset:/app_icon.png' }}
  style={{ width: 40, height: 40 }}
/>
```

**Image show from network :**

```
<Image source={{uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png'}}
   style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />
```

**From base64 Image data :**

```
<Image style={{
    width: 51,
    height: 51,
    resizeMode: 'contain'
  }}
  source={{
    uri:
      'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='
  }}
/>
```

More Information about image is on this link : [React native Image](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images)